# Adding Action Bar items during run time

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

Is there anyway to add Action Bar items on the event of a button click or a list item click? I know about Action Mode but it is intended for multiple choices. So, my user interface requirement is that on clicking the list item, there should be a new action bar item for editing the selected item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is the entire reason why ActionMode was created. Catering for multiple choices is just one option available to you when using ActionMode.

You should really be using this rather than trying to find some other hack around it.

It provides callbacks to add action items and remove them once you are done.